# How to find the peak current and Vswce of this IC - NCV3063

Tags: design, boost, converter

I need to design a boost converter using this IC. From (7.5V to 16.5V) to 23V. Load current max is 255mA.

I am having some difficulty in understanding some of the design calculation.

How will I calculate the peak current, Ipk and the Vswce parameter?
And moreover, how does the SWC and SWE pin work? Please explain.

> [NCV3063](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/NCP3063-D.PDF)

Comment: Hi, You've effectively asked the same question again (but this time giving more of the required information) here: "[Calculating the peak current of my boost converter](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/419242/101852)". Therefore since *that* one has got some answers, I'm voting to close *this* one as a duplicate (despite this being asked first). IMHO it would be better if you delete this answer, since it has no answers. (Note: repeating the same question is not allowed here. If no-one answers your question, see [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers).) Thanks!

Comment: Too late to edit it now, but I meant to say above: "IMHO it would be better if you delete this **question**, since it has no answers".