# Calculating the peak current of my boost converter

Tags: current, dc-dc-converter, boost

I am stuck with calculating the peak current through the inductor in a boost converter. Can you please check if I am right?

I<sub>peak</sub> = (V<sub>max</sub> / R2) = 18 / 1000 = 0.018 A. So, my peak current through the inductor is just 18 mA? Am I doing it correctly?

If this is correct, how will I account for the V<sub>ce</sub> drop inside the pin1 and pin2 of the IC?

The Darlington transistor inside the IC is just like a normal transistor. I have added two transistors outside the IC instead of using the Darlington switch in the IC for thermal purposes.

Can you please help me with the calculation of V<sub>swce</sub> and I<sub>peak</sub>? The calculation of V<sub>swce</sub> is not mentioned in the datasheet.

The calculation of I<sub>peak</sub> is mentioned in the datasheet, but is my approach of calculating the peak current through the inductor right?

[image: My circuit]

Answer (score 1):

From **Figure 4. Block Diagram** in the [datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/NCP3063-D.PDF), you can see pin 6 is compared with pin 7 of the IC.
Note that the + input of the comparator lies 200mV **lower** than Vcc.
When pin 7 becomes lower than (Vcc-200mV) the peak detection will be activated (and so, the Darlington transistor will be disabled).

From your posted schematic, the (peak) current through the inductor causes a voltage drop across R1.
This voltage drop is divided by resistors R2 and R3.
So, the voltage on pin 7 will be:
\begin{equation}(V_{cc} - I * R_1 ) * R_3 / (R_2+R_3)\end{equation}

The peak detection will be activated when
\begin{equation}
V_{cc} * R_3/(R_2+R_3) - I * R_1 *R_3/(R_2+R_3) < V_{cc}-200mV
\end{equation}
Note that this depends on the current through the inductor **as well as the applied voltage Vcc**.

R3 is unclear to me, but 0M18 = 180K makes sense, and pick Vcc = 15V
\begin{eqnarray*}
15V * 180/181 - I * 0.082E * 180/181  &<& 14.8V\\
14.917V - I * 0.082E * 180/181  &<& 14.8V\\
117mV &<& I * 0.082E * 180/181\\
118mV &<& I * 0.082E\\
118mV / 0.082E &<& I\\
I &>& 1.44A \\
\end{eqnarray*}
So, max peak cuurent through inductor is 1.44 A

When e.g. Vcc = 10V, the same circuit limits the current to 1.78 A

Comment: Thank you very much. Now, I clearly understand this calculation and working. Can you please help with Vswce? How do I calculate Vswce? It is not given in datasheet.

Comment: Why would you want to know Vswce?

Comment: In the datasheet of NCV3063, Fig.15 we need to calculate Vswce to find Ton/Toff.

Comment: It is given in the datasheet, page 5, especially Figure 9, but also in Figures 7,8 and 10.

Comment: Yes. But I am not able to understand. Please explain how to calculate Vswce like how you clearly explained Ipeak calculation. Please. Sorry for the trouble

Comment: VSWCE is determined by IL(avg), which requires knowledge of VSWCE... Either choose an average value for it from Figure 9, e.g. 1.6V and you'll see compare the result with VSWCE=1.4V and VSWCE=1.8V ... probably not that big variation

Comment: Or try using the equations provided by UweD. Using d = t_on / (t_on+t_off)

Comment: I calculated Vswce = Rds(on) * Ipeak. Is this right? According to my calculation Vswce=0.276*1.33=0.368V.

Comment: No. The NCP3063 has no Rds(on). Rds(on) is a parameter of a mosfet, the NCP3063 has a darlington. Moreover, you'd better use IL(avg).

Comment: PS. Substituting d = t_on / (t_on+t_off) in UweD's first equation and elaborating it gives ton / toff = Vout - Vin / Vin, the same equation as in Figure 15, except that the Vforward and VSWCE have been neglected (which is common practice). So, i'd suggest to neglet VSWCE or use 1.6V

Comment: I am using an external MOSFET. I am taking that Rds(on) of that external MOSFET. Like the one connected in Fig.25 of the datasheet.

Comment: According to my design of the boost converter in my board, I am measuring the values in scope and multimeter. This is a reference board. For Vin of 16V, The voltage at pin1(SWC) of the IC =15.05V in DMM. Pin2 (SWE), I am measuring in scope, I am getting a peak-peakof some 15.8V with 30.6% duty and Max amplitude of 13.8V. Now, Vswce=difference between the pins 1 and 2. How to calculate this now? Please help

Comment: You cannot use the first equation of Figure 15 of the datasheet. It only is applicable for setups as in Figure 19 where the IL(avg) goes through the darlington. For your schematic,IL(avg) goes through Q1 and you should therefore replace VSWCE by Vds of Q1 in the first equation of Figure 15.

Comment: OK. from my measurement of pin1 and pin2 output voltages, how to get Vswce,? Or in general, can you please tell me how to calculate the voltage difference between a switching Vout pin (in this case, pin2) and a constant Vout pin (in this case, pin1)

Answer (score -1):

In a boost converter the inductor peak current (relevant for saturation) is inductor average current plus maximum ripple. Your modulation index is

\$d = 1 - \frac{V_{IN}}{V_{OUT}}\$

The average inductor current, depending on your specific load \$I_{OUT}\$, is

\$I_{L,avg} = \frac{I_{OUT}}{1-d}\$

The ripple current is (depending on your switching frequency \$f\$)

\$\Delta I_{L,peak-peak} = \frac{V_{IN}}{L} \cdot \frac{d}{f}\$

Finally we get for continuous conduction mode

\$I_{L,peak} = I_{L,avg} + \frac{1}{2} \Delta I_{L,peak-peak}\$

while for discontinuous conduction mode the maximum current is simply

\$I_{L,peak} = \Delta I_{L,peak-peak}\$

Since a range of input voltage is given in your schematics, you will at least have to check for 8 V and 18 V which gives the higher inductor peak current.

Your maximum input current is specified as 0.6 A, so the maximum inductor peak current will be higher than this.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong, but the peak inductor does not need to be summed up with the average current inductor. You formula of the peak-to-peak is valid, but considers already the entire slope from 0A to Ipeak as the worse case scenario. Double check with a drawing and with, for example, an app note like SLVA797.

Comment: In continuous modulation which I assumed (maybe I was wrong here) you have to add the average current. In discontinuous modulation you must not.

Comment: Thanks for clarify. I assume by modulation index you mean duty cycle D. So making a calculation, means than in a classical boost, imposing a maximum inductor (absolute) peak current, with higher input voltages, the converter can output more current, with lower p-to-p current. Makes sense?

Comment: (Seems you need to edit the question to put the +1)